# How to pass Special Character in query string using asp.net and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I wanna pass `%20` in Query string. But in code behind it will considered as space in code behind.

How can i do that?

I am passing querystring using asp.net and also from javascript.

Please help me out for the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass value from Asp.net code behind use `Server.UrlEncode(%20)`

When you pass value from JavaScript use `encodeURIComponent('%20')` (which will yield `%2520`)

Answer (score 2):

Pass `%2520` to escape your `%`, that's how.